# Value Error while classifying for multidimensional output classes using SVMs

Tags: python, classification, svm, multiclass-classification, supervised-learning

I am trying to fit & classify my data using SVMs.
My input data consists of 11 features (dimensions) with 1335 samples, and output data consists of 17 classes (1335x17)

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
svccl = svclassifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

(and even for kernel = poly)
I get the following error:

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (934, 17) instead.
```

Same error comes when I try to classify using Naive Bayes classifier

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB 
gnb = GaussianNB().fit(x_train, y_train) 
gnb_predictions = gnb.predict(x_test)
```

Where am i wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 1):

`SVC` and `GaussianNB` won't support multiple target variable classification.
Hence it won't accept anything else than 1d array to tackle that you would need to fit one classifier per target.

There is already API [Multioutput classification](https://sklearn.org/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-classification)

You can combine this with any classifier you want.

**Combining Mulitoutput with SVC**

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(934, 100)
Y = np.random.randint(17, size = [934, 17])

n_samples, n_features = X.shape 

svc = SVC()
multi_target_forest = MultiOutputClassifier(svc, n_jobs=-1)

multi_target_forest.fit(X, Y).predict(X)
```

**Combining Mulitoutput with GaussianNB**

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB 
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(934, 100)
Y = np.random.randint(17, size = [934, 17])

n_samples, n_features = X.shape

gnb = GaussianNB()
multi_target_forest = MultiOutputClassifier(gnb, n_jobs=-1)

multi_target_forest.fit(X, Y).predict(X)
```

Comment: I got the following error: ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class

Comment: The error you mentioned is it for the example snippets I provided above? if you took that as a base code and modified the configurations, I would suggest checking up on API documentation or look up on ClassifierChain if you want to do something custom.

Comment: I followed the API documentation provided by you, and then tried my hands on the code. I converted my data into ndarray (as mentioned in the documentation), and then followed further. every time i get the same error: 
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

Now I'm not able to overcome this error!

Comment: it seems like you are passing float/double values in y, if you are using something like logistic regression then it would expect you to have integer values

Comment: Yes float values are passed, as all the columns are normalised to 1. But my target values are integers, and only input features are float values. Moreover, I'm using classifiers (not regression model), so i don't think so classifiers have problem handling floating pt values? @ anuragwagh